# Armstrong Axioms - functional dependencies

Tags: functional-dependencies

I need to solve the following past paper question but I can't seem to understand it.

[image: Question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase what you have been given:

```
 A -> B and B -> C still hold
```

you are asked:

```
Show that A -> B,C is true
```

Since `A -> B` and `B -> C` (given above), then because of the transitivity rule we can say

```
 A -> C
```

Now working backwards from the decomposition rule we can say that because

```
 A -> B
 A -> C

 then...

 A -> B,C
```

and there you go.